# Accessing object within object by value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am learning React-Redux and I have an issue navigating through the objects in my JSON file. I have the following file JSON, the file is designed to render out a side navigation:

```
export default function(){
    return [
            {
            catId:"parMenu1",
            parentCat:"Genres",
            subcat:[
                {
                    genre:"8Bit",
                    genreId:"1"
                },
                {
                    genre:"Acid House",
                    genreId:"2"
                }
           ]
           },
           {
            catId:"parMenu2",
            parentCat:"sounds",
            subcat:[
                {
                    genre:"blah",
                    genreId:"3"
                },
                {
                    genre:"blah House",
                    genreId:"4"
                }
           ]
    ]
}
```

I have the JSON file mapped to state props for a component. The component looks like so:

```
class BrowseByCont extends Component {  
    render () {
        return (
            <div className="browseByContInner">
                {
                    console.log(this.props.reducerSidenav[0].catId)
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        reducerSidenav:state.reducerSidenav
    };
}
```

I am trying to reach the subcats object within the parent object. The JSON object is linked to a variable called "reducerSidenav". So far I have managed to get this far into my JSON file: `this.props.reducerSidenav[0].catId`. this spits out the value `parMenu1` which is the "parent" object I want to target. Where I am stuck though is I am trying to achieve two things:

firstly - I would like to access the first "parent" object by without having to refer to the first item in the array: `reducerSidenav[0]` but rather by find the `catId` with a value of `parMenu1`. This is because this list will be dynamic in future and referring to the first array object is not reliable.

secondy - I would then like to access the `subcat` object and get to the value thats associated to the key `genre` ie to return the value "8Bit"

Comment: There is no JSON above. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: ok good to know and thanks for clarifying. Question still stands though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/find) to achieve both things.

```
class BrowseByCont extends React.Component {  
    render () {
        let first = this.props.reducerSidenav.find(item => item.catId === "parMenu1");
        let second = first.subcat.find(subcat => subcat.genre === "8Bit")
        return (
            <div className="browseByContInner">
                <div>{first.catId}</div>
                <div>{second.genre}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Edit**

In order to print all the subcats, you have to use `.map()`

```
class BrowseByCont extends React.Component {  
    render () {
        let first = this.props.reducerSidenav.find(item => item.catId === "parMenu1");
        return (
            <div className="browseByContInner">
                {first.subcat.map(genreItem => 
                    <div key={genreItem.genreId}>{genreItem.genre}</div>)
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/59702/)

Comment: Good to know about find. I tried it before but I was using it in the wrong way I think. Your answer spits out the values that I want but not in the way that I want. I was wanting to map all the subcat items and return them into divs. I have written a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/74pgqby5/ of what I am trying to achieve. At the moment its giving me an error: A valid React element (or null) must be returned. so I guess i'm not targeting the map correctly?

Comment: this is the correct way to achieve what you want in that jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/59721/

Comment: Thanks QoP that works but i'm confused as to how you are referencing "8Bit". Lets say that I change the object down the line and "8Bit" is no longer the first item in the subcats array. Would there be a more generic way of targeting the subcats array?

Comment: Sorry i just saw that the second let was not needed. Was confusing me. Do you want to post the answer or shall I?

Comment: if you could also tell me what the syntax item => is doing just after the .find( that would be really helpfull! Cheers

Comment: that's an `arrow function`, it's a new feature of ES6, [ES5 equivalent](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Ces2015-loose%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Creact%2Cstage-0&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=let%20first%20%3D%20this.props.reducerSidenav.find(item%20%3D%3E%20item.catId%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22parMenu1%22)%3B)

Comment: ok and just before it you used "item". Are you declaring a function called item?

Comment: no, we are passing an anonymous function to `.find()` and `item` is the first *parameter* of that function.